# Run a command without pre or post commands

Tags: npm

Npm has support for running commands before and after a command by prepending either `pre` or `post` to that command name. So `npm run build` will trigger `prebuild` and `postbuild` if those commands are defined.

There are cases where I want to run `build` *without* the other commands.

Is this possible?

Comment: `npm run build --ignore-scripts` ?

Comment: I even checked `run --help` ... thank you